# Cannot resolve symbol 'fontPath'

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout

It says "Android resource linking failed" and **style attribute 'attr/fontPath' not found**, my code in `styles.xml` file is

```xml
  <style name="Regular" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <item name="fontPath">fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.otf</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SemiBold" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <item name="fontPath">fonts/SourceSansPro-Semibold.otf</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Light" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <item name="fontPath">fonts/SourceSansPro-LightIt.otf</item>
    </style>
```

I've tried to clean the project but it didn't work

Comment: Are you using the Calligraphy library in your project?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, I just checked it and realize "import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;
" didn't work..

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you might not have that library added properly.

Comment: @MikeM. "import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.bitmap_recycle.BitmapPool;
" didn't work either, but I can't find a latest version..

Comment: @MikeM. Is it because the libraries are too old?

Comment: Look in your app's `build.gradle`, in the `dependencies`. Are there any errors?

Comment: @MikeM. It looks fine. I used " implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
"

Comment: Hmm, well, you might try cleaning/rebuilding your project, and Invalidate Caches/Restart. As for the library version, yeah, that is rather old, and it will likely fail on Android Pie and above, IIRC. Calligraphy had to be rewritten when the restrictions on reflection were introduced. The latest edition is 3+: https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy. Is this an old project that you're trying to update?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes I'm trying to make changes to an old project